# Transfer data from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic

I transfer data from sheet "instru" to the sheet "data" using this code.

```
Option Explicit
Sub lastrow()
Dim wsS1 As Worksheet 'Sheet1
Dim wsS2 As Worksheet 'sheet2
Dim lastrow As Long
Set wsS1 = Sheets("Instru")
Set wsS2 = Sheets("data")

With wsS1
    lastrow = range("A:A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    wsS1.range("A5:KU5" & lastrow).Copy wsS2.range("A1:KU11440" & lastrow)
End With

End Sub
```

I want to achieve the same for a dynamic range. It should count the rows present in sheet "instru" and copy only that many rows to "data" sheet.

E.g. I want to copy ("A1:D1") based on the count of column "A" in "instru".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Last Row Range

```
Sub lastRow()

    Dim wsS1 As Worksheet 'Sheet1
    Dim wsS2 As Worksheet 'sheet2
    Dim lastR As Long

    Set wsS1 = Sheets("Instru")
    Set wsS2 = Sheets("data")

    With wsS1
        lastR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A5:KU" & lastR).Copy wsS2.Range("A1")
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: if i want to copy ("A1:D1") sheet "data"  based on the count of column "A" in "instru" sheet what changes will the above code have?